# HSD.test row names error. How do I check row names?

Tags: r, anova, tukey

I have a dataframe for which I did a two-way ANOVA.

`dput(m3)`

> structure(list(Delta = c(-40, -40, -40, -40, -31.7, -29.3, -27.8, 
>   -26.7, -26.2, -25.4, -24.7, -23.1, -23, -22.9, -22.4, -22.2, 
>   -21.4, -21, -20.8, -15.1, -14.9, -14.1, -6.2, -6.2, -6, -5.3, 
>   -4.9), Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
>   3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("int", "pen + int", "ter + pen"), class = "factor"), 
>       Between = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
>       1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
>       ), Relative = structure(c(5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
>       5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
>       2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1&2", "2&3", "2&4", "2&5", "3&4", 
>       "3&5", "3&6", "4&6"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
>   -27L))

```
library(agricolae)
aov.2sum=aov(Delta.~Location*X.between, data=m3)
```

I want to analyze the data using a *HSD.test* as I have for another dataframe using the same features. 
I am following the code format in the package manual as below.

```
tx <- with(m3, interaction(Location, X.between))
amod <-aov(Delta~tx, data=m3)
test=HSD.test(amod, "tx", group=TRUE)
```

Then I receive the following error

> Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
>     duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘int.0’, ‘pen + int.1’, ‘pen + int.2’, ‘te + int.0’, ‘te + int.1’

Upon further analysis I see that my duplicate row names error is related to my X.between feature. When I use the following code I get the same duplicate row names error:

```
HSD.test(amod, "X.between", group=TRUE)
>> Error in data.frame(row.names = means[, 1], means[, 2:6]) : 
  duplicate row.names: 0, 1, 2
```

How are row names chosen for the HSD.test? 
Then how can I change my row names? Or just avoid this duplication error?

Thank you for all and any help.

Comment: This is not reproducible so it is not possible to answer your question. You need to provide the data (or a subset) or data with a similar organization to yours - there are many data sets available on R. You should indicate what packages you are using. I was able to find `HSD.test` in `agricolae` but where is `internation`? Did you mean `interaction`? Try `summary(amod)` and see what that tells you.

Comment: So I updated by question with a bit of my dataset and the clarifications. Thank you.
But I don't know why summary(amod) would help.

Comment: A picture of a bit of your data is not useful. We cannot see what types of variables these are and we cannot run your code ourselves. Use `dput` to give us at least 15-20 lines of the data. Looking at `summary(amod)` will tell us if the anova ran successfully. The error message is about row names. Try comparing `nrow(m3)` to `length(unique(rownames(m3))` to see if you have duplicate row names in the original data. If so, `rownames(m3) <- NULL` will remove them and replace them with numbers 1, 2, 3, . . .

Comment: Currently `nrow(m3)` and `length(unique(rownames(m3)))` are the same

Comment: Are you still getting the error? In my previous comment I showed you how to clear the rownames.

Comment: Yes I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Using your included data I do not get the error. The data you included has different column names, "Delta" not "Delta." and "Between" not "X.between". The error message seems to suggest that your group names are being used as row names but that does not happen in the data you included here.